# Pass method as functional interface in Scala

Tags: scala

I need to pass a `public static int isRequired(Configuration config, Field field, ValidationOutput problems)` as a `io.debezium.config.Field.Validator` in Scala.

While in Java, this simply is a call `MyObject::isRequired` I cannot seem to make it work in Scala.

I tried wrapping the `handler(MyObject.isRequired)` manually via:

```
def handler[Valid](h: Valid) =
    new Field.Validator {
        override def validate(config: Configuration, field: Field, problems: Field.ValidationOutput): Int =
            h(config, field, problems)
    }
```

but for whatever reason Scala seems to handle the method references differently than what I expect.

What is the easiest way of making this compile/work?

Answer (score 0):

What does work in this case is:

```
def handler(h: (Configuration, Field, Field.ValidationOutput) => Int): Field.Validator =
    new Field.Validator {
        override def validate(config: Configuration, field: Field, problems: Field.ValidationOutput): Int =
            h(config, field, problems)
    }
```

So my problems were two-fold:

1. forgot to specify the return type
2. I assumed `Valid` would be of type `(Configuration, Field, Field.ValidationOutput) => Int`, which it obviously was not. At least a bit of the Scala type system I seem to not understand fully yet.